# SQL Server for testing on the web

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Is there a possibility to connect to a SQL Server database that is on the web and create there some tables queries etc. for testing purposes?

This would be useful when you don't want to install SQL Server (e.g. you are on another OS) but still are interested in this technology. It would be great if there would a possibility to connect to your database created there programmatically too.

Comment: You can connect to any database that the running application can see.  In general, it's usually frowned upon to have a database openly exposed on the web, though.  You'll want to make sure you're well versed in securing that database.  A far more common practice is to put the database behind a firewall and expose a web service for applications to integrate and access the data.

Comment: How big a database are you thinking of testing? Do you want hundreds of tables and millions of rows or just enough to prove a query will work?

Comment: @Tony From the start I think a few tables will be sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `SQL Fiddle` and run your queries in SQL Server 2008 R2 or 2012 mode:

http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 3):

Check out http://sqlfiddle.com/

> A tool for easy online testing and sharing of database problems and their solutions.

[image: SQL Fiddle Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You would have to pay for any server you use on the cloud, MS offer [SQL Database](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/data-management/) (the rather vague name for what was known as SQL Azure)

[Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/windows/) have also recently started to offer SQL Server cloud hosting.

You could pay for a month's testing and then the database would be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

sites like freesqldatabase.com will give you credentials to easily connect to their SQL Server database for free for testing purposes. You can also take advantage of Google or Amazon free tier in web hosting to create and get access to sql database for free.

The best option for testing purposes is to create a local database on your PC you can access similarly to that on the web for free and very simple to do. Here is a video I found that can point you in right direction. It will show you how to create a local database you can use for testing purposes
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5DhHYQlnq8&ab_channel=ChrisDyck